# eth_sign method fail with @walletconnect/sign-client and @web3modal/standalone

Tags: javascript, wallet, wallet-connect, web3modal

I am currently trying to use the **eth_sign** method with **WalletConnect** to sign a message from a wallet application, here Spot.

To do this I took the [js example project](https://github.com/WalletConnect/web3modal-examples/tree/main/html-standalone) available on the git of WalletConnect with the chosen configuration (html-standalone).

I modify the code to first try the personnal_sign method with the [data from the documentation](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/advanced/rpc-reference/ethereum-rpc#personal_sign) And here is the code:

```
const namespaces = {
  eip155: {
    methods: ["eth_sign","personal_sign"],
    chains: ["eip155:1"],
    events: ["accountsChanged"],},};

...

signButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  try {
    if (signClient) {
      let params = ["0xdeadbeaf",session.namespaces.eip155.accounts[0].split(':')[2],]
      let method = "personal_sign"
      const result = await signClient.request({
        topic: session.topic,
        chainId: "eip155:1",
        request: {
          id: 1,
          jsonrpc: "2.0",
          method: method,
          params: params,
        },});
      if (result) {
        console.log(result);}}
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);}});
```

And this works correctly, I do have the modal opening in my wallet application and then I do get my message signature in reply.

However when I try to use the eth_sign method with the [data from the documentation](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/advanced/rpc-reference/ethereum-rpc#eth_sign) I don't have a working behavior. And here is the code:

```
signButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  try {
    if (signClient) {
      let params = [session.namespaces.eip155.accounts[0].split(':')[2],"0xdeadbeaf",]
      let method = "eth_sign"
      const result = await signClient.request({
        topic: session.topic,
        chainId: "eip155:1",
        request: {
          id: 1,
          jsonrpc: "2.0",
          method: method,
          params: params,
        },});
      if (result) {
        console.log(result);}}
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);}});
```

When the click is done, an error mode appears in my wallet application (Spot):

> An error has occurred please try again later.

Mobile error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF87w.jpg

In the console of my browser I also have an error message which is very brief:

> {context: 'client'} 'error'

Desktop error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7tzo.png

I tried to take several other wallet application compatible with **WalletConnect v2** but nothing makes it. I can't understand why the **eth_sign** request doesn't pass with the example data while **personal_sign** does.

A sentence in the documentation caught my attention, it is present in the Note of the [documentation](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/advanced/rpc-reference/ethereum-rpc#eth_sign) of **eth_sign** and of the other **eth_XX methods**. Unfortunately I don't understand the meaning of this sentence although I think it is an interesting lead:

> Note the address to sign with must be unlocked.

If someone who has already used this tool would have a lead I would obviously be interested.